# Function to pass data file and colums with names in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I want to run a ggplot for different set of variables. I am trying to make a function which can take as arguments, the data, variables and their names that I want to label later in plots. Following is an example  what I want. Could you please suggest what would be the proper way to pass these arguments and get the results? 
Because I am getting the following error
    Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors

```
v1 <- rep(c(2,4,6,8,10), each = 6)  
v2 <- rep(1:3,10)  
v3 <-runif(30,0.01,0.3)
v4 <-runif(30,0.05,0.9)
combined_data <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)  
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1<-myplot(combined_data, v3,v2,v1,"alpha1","beta","gamma")
p2<-myplot(combined_data, v4,v2,v1,"alpha2","beta","gamma")
grid.arrange(p1,p2) 

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
myplot<-function(data, xvar, yvar, legend, xlab="", ylab="", factor="") 
{
 p<-ggplot(data,aes(x=xvar,y=yvar))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="smooth",aes(color=as.factor(legend)),linetype=2)+
  labs(x="xlab", y = "ylab", color = "factor")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
      )
   return(p)
  }
```

Comment: You could use `aes_string` to map all your variables to ggplot call. No need for `aes_string` in `labs`, though. `labs(x = xlab, y = ylab)` (no quotes) should work.

Answer (score 1):

`aes_string` is the easiest way to achieve this. However, because you want to also set the color variable to a `factor`, you also need to use the `paste0("factor(", legend, ")")` construct. Here's the full code.

```
myplot<-function(data, xvar, yvar, legend, xlab="", ylab="", factor="") 
{
  p<-ggplot(data, aes_string(x=xvar,y=yvar))+
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="smooth", 
                 aes_string(color=paste0("factor(", legend, ")")), 
                 linetype=2) +
    labs(x=xlab, y = ylab, color = factor)+
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
    )
  return(p)
}
## --------------------------------------------------------------------------
p1 <- myplot(combined_data, "v3", "v2", "v1", "alpha1", "beta", "gamma")
p2 <- myplot(combined_data, "v4", "v2", "v1", "alpha2", "beta", "gamma")
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Is there a general way to consider v1 in     aes(color=factor(eval(substitute(v1))    becuse I may have to use different variable say V3 some time...

Comment: See my edits. You can just use `paste` and don't need `eval(substitute))` at all.

Comment: In the case of above example, if we have 10 plots then the colors of obtained lines(some) are very similar to each other...makes it hard to distinguish. How I can change the color in the above code, in a way that the lines are identifialbe?

Comment: Ten identifiable colors is tough no matter what. See e.g. (http://colorbrewer2.org/). You can use `?scale_color_brewer` or `?scale_color_manual` to change color scheme. But it'll still be difficult to distinguish ten colors.